# Level Selector in most games now?

Tags: android

I am wondering what is used to create a level or object selector such as this in a game?

Any one has an idea of what is the best way for creating something like this?

[image]

Comment: You should add some info to accompany the image explaining how that user interface works; viewed alone it doesn't convey enough about the UX (user experience) you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the very polished games that you see in Android are not using standard Views for each graphical element you see on the screen. In order to get good performance, pretty much all of them use OpenGL whether directly or indirectly. There probably isn't a common control that they all use.

That said, if you want something somewhat equivalent in the normal Android View hierarachy, you can take a look at the [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) control or the [ViewPager](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html).

Comment: You could build this with Gallery pretty easily. You have to make an adapter that passes a view instead of an image.

Comment: Could you give an example of overriding the adapter that passes a view insteand of aimage?